# Set Culture in HttpModule with cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, currentculture

I'm currently looking for a better solution to what I have now. I hoping someone could help me on this one.

I'm creating a web page and I'm trying to set the culture of the website manually with cookies.

I have 2 buttons

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="LanguageNL" OnCommand="Language_Command" CommandName="Language" CommandArgument="nl" ImageUrl="~/Images/Flags/nl.png" style="margin-left: 0px" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="LanguageEN" OnCommand="Language_Command" CommandName="Language" CommandArgument="en" ImageUrl="~/Images/Flags/gb.png" style="margin-left: 5px" />

    protected void Language_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Do Command");
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(e.CommandName);
        cookie.Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

and to set the page culture I'm using a IHttpModule like this

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

public class DartsGhentAuthorization : IHttpModule
{
    public DartsGhentAuthorization() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        application.Response.Write("Begin Request");
        HttpCookie languageCookie = application.Request.Cookies["Language"];
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("nl");
        if (languageCookie != null)
            culture = new CultureInfo(languageCookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing happens in the page life cycle.
When I press a button to change the language, the page refreshes but
first the HttpModule is called and only after that the page load and then the button commands are triggered. Which means I first look for the culture and only later I set the language in one page request. To fix my problem I added a response.redirect to reload my page so the language is changed as intended but is there a way to do this better?

I'm using HttpModule because I'm trying not to set the page culture in an overload. Also I'm creating my own page authorization so I will need the httpmodule for more website integration.

Answer (score 0):

you may add some hack to your asp button with help with javascript to clear your cookie so that before the request begins you have no cookie containing the language so it will set the new one 
here is Example

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="LanguageNL" OnClientClick="ClearCookie();"  OnCommand="Language_Command" CommandName="Language" CommandArgument="nl" ImageUrl="~/Images/Flags/nl.png" style="margin-left: 0px" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClientClick="ClearCookie();" ID="LanguageEN" OnCommand="Language_Command" CommandName="Language" CommandArgument="en" ImageUrl="~/Images/Flags/gb.png" style="margin-left: 5px" />
```

and in your JavaScript Add Function Clear Cookie

```
function ClearCookie(){
//Do Clear Cookie
}
```

Comment: the httpmodule will set the default culture which is NL if no cookie exists. this would work great if I want to switch to NL but not the other way around. But it could be an idea to set the cookies with javascript and then do a  refresh page